# azure conditional access logout after a specified time

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, logout

I want to set an expiry time for my web app so that after 1 hour the user will automatically be logged out.  It seems that azure now have a new feature called 'conditional access'.  Firstly I have to have a premium account (so yet more money) and secondly I cant find anything in the documentation that shows how to use it to log someone out after a specified time.  Has anyone used this feature yet ? how can this be done ?

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using OpenID Connect and Cookie authentication middleware to protect your web app, for your requirement, I assumed that you could add a custom claim named `loggedTicks` and check the time interval under the `OnValidateIdentity` of `CookieAuthenticationProvider`, then explicitly invoke the sign out operation against your web application and AAD. Here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
        ExpireTimeSpan=TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = ctx => {

                var loggedClaim=ctx.Identity.FindFirst("loggedTicks")?.Value;
                if (loggedClaim != null)
                {
                    var loggedDateTime = new DateTime(long.Parse(loggedClaim), DateTimeKind.Utc);

                    if (loggedDateTime.AddHours(1) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        ctx.RejectIdentity();
                        ctx.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    }
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            }
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async (x) =>
                    {
                        var identity = x.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        //add a additional claim which represents the current user logged UTC time ticks
                        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("loggedTicks", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()));

                        await Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, big help.  only one small issue though, how can I enforce the logout  and go to the logout screen without user interaction ? at the moment, after the predetermined logout time, the logout process itself only works if a user has some interaction with the site, ie clicks a menu item , etc, so despite the logout time having expired, the screen still shows the last page they visited

Comment: For automatic logout, I assume that you may continuously send a ajax request to a anonymously accessed action which would validate the `loggedTicks` claim at a specified interval of time (e.g. 5s), if the validation fails, then you could redirect the client user to a specific page which need to be authorized access.